# Clang 3.2 on RHEL5 not compiling simple test program

Tags: c++, compilation, clang, rhel, rhel5

I'm trying to compile a simple "hello world" test program, which is shown below as "hello.cpp".

**hello.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::cout << "Hello world!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

To compile, I'm using

```
$ clang --version
clang version 3.2 (tags/RELEASE_32/final 191651)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
```

on a RHEL5 OS, where clang was installed by following [these steps](http://www.domaigne.com/blog/computing/install-latest-llvmclang-on-fedora/#Fn01) exactly.

But when I try to compile, I get tons of errors that I don't understand:

```
$ clang hello.cpp -o hello
In file included from hello.cpp:1:
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/iostream:43:
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/ostream:43:
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/ios:42:
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/iosfwd:45:
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/c++io.h:38:
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/gthr.h:132:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/gthr-default.h:100:1: error: weakref declaration must have
      internal linkage
__gthrw(pthread_once)
^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/gthr-default.h:81:23: note: expanded from macro '__gthrw'
#define __gthrw(name) __gthrw2(__gthrw_ ## name,name,name)
                      ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/gthr-default.h:72:46: note: expanded from macro '__gthrw2'
  extern __typeof(type) name __attribute__ ((__weakref__(#name2))); \
                                             ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/gthr-default.h:101:1: error: weakref declaration must have
      internal linkage
__gthrw(pthread_getspecific)
^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/gthr-default.h:81:23: note: expanded from macro '__gthrw'
#define __gthrw(name) __gthrw2(__gthrw_ ## name,name,name)
                      ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/gthr-default.h:72:46: note: expanded from macro '__gthrw2'
  extern __typeof(type) name __attribute__ ((__weakref__(#name2))); \
                                             ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/gthr-default.h:102:1: error: weakref declaration must have
      internal linkage
__gthrw(pthread_setspecific)
^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/gthr-default.h:81:23: note: expanded from macro '__gthrw'
#define __gthrw(name) __gthrw2(__gthrw_ ## name,name,name)
                      ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/gthr-default.h:72:46: note: expanded from macro '__gthrw2'
  extern __typeof(type) name __attribute__ ((__weakref__(#name2))); \
                                             ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/gthr-default.h:103:1: error: weakref declaration must have
      internal linkage
__gthrw(pthread_create)
^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/gthr-default.h:81:23: note: expanded from macro '__gthrw'
#define __gthrw(name) __gthrw2(__gthrw_ ## name,name,name)
                      ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/gthr-default.h:72:46: note: expanded from macro '__gthrw2'
  extern __typeof(type) name __attribute__ ((__weakref__(#name2))); \
                                             ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/gthr-default.h:104:1: error: weakref declaration must have
      internal linkage
__gthrw(pthread_cancel)
^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/gthr-default.h:81:23: note: expanded from macro '__gthrw'
#define __gthrw(name) __gthrw2(__gthrw_ ## name,name,name)
                      ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/gthr-default.h:72:46: note: expanded from macro '__gthrw2'
  extern __typeof(type) name __attribute__ ((__weakref__(#name2))); \
                                             ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/gthr-default.h:105:1: error: weakref declaration must have
      internal linkage
__gthrw(pthread_mutex_lock)
^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/gthr-default.h:81:23: note: expanded from macro '__gthrw'
#define __gthrw(name) __gthrw2(__gthrw_ ## name,name,name)
                      ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/gthr-default.h:72:46: note: expanded from macro '__gthrw2'
  extern __typeof(type) name __attribute__ ((__weakref__(#name2))); \
                                             ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/gthr-default.h:106:1: error: weakref declaration must have
      internal linkage
__gthrw(pthread_mutex_trylock)
^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/gthr-default.h:81:23: note: expanded from macro '__gthrw'
#define __gthrw(name) __gthrw2(__gthrw_ ## name,name,name)
                      ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/gthr-default.h:72:46: note: expanded from macro '__gthrw2'
  extern __typeof(type) name __attribute__ ((__weakref__(#name2))); \
                                             ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/gthr-default.h:107:1: error: weakref declaration must have
      internal linkage
__gthrw(pthread_mutex_unlock)
^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/gthr-default.h:81:23: note: expanded from macro '__gthrw'
#define __gthrw(name) __gthrw2(__gthrw_ ## name,name,name)
                      ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/gthr-default.h:72:46: note: expanded from macro '__gthrw2'
  extern __typeof(type) name __attribute__ ((__weakref__(#name2))); \
                                             ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/gthr-default.h:108:1: error: weakref declaration must have
      internal linkage
__gthrw(pthread_mutex_init)
^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/gthr-default.h:81:23: note: expanded from macro '__gthrw'
#define __gthrw(name) __gthrw2(__gthrw_ ## name,name,name)
                      ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/gthr-default.h:72:46: note: expanded from macro '__gthrw2'
  extern __typeof(type) name __attribute__ ((__weakref__(#name2))); \
                                             ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/gthr-default.h:109:1: error: weakref declaration must have
      internal linkage
__gthrw(pthread_cond_broadcast)
^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/gthr-default.h:81:23: note: expanded from macro '__gthrw'
#define __gthrw(name) __gthrw2(__gthrw_ ## name,name,name)
                      ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/gthr-default.h:72:46: note: expanded from macro '__gthrw2'
  extern __typeof(type) name __attribute__ ((__weakref__(#name2))); \
                                             ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/gthr-default.h:110:1: error: weakref declaration must have
      internal linkage
__gthrw(pthread_cond_wait)
^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/gthr-default.h:81:23: note: expanded from macro '__gthrw'
#define __gthrw(name) __gthrw2(__gthrw_ ## name,name,name)
                      ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/gthr-default.h:72:46: note: expanded from macro '__gthrw2'
  extern __typeof(type) name __attribute__ ((__weakref__(#name2))); \
                                             ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/gthr-default.h:113:1: error: weakref declaration must have
      internal linkage
__gthrw(pthread_key_create)
^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/gthr-default.h:81:23: note: expanded from macro '__gthrw'
#define __gthrw(name) __gthrw2(__gthrw_ ## name,name,name)
                      ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/gthr-default.h:72:46: note: expanded from macro '__gthrw2'
  extern __typeof(type) name __attribute__ ((__weakref__(#name2))); \
                                             ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/gthr-default.h:114:1: error: weakref declaration must have
      internal linkage
__gthrw(pthread_key_delete)
^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/gthr-default.h:81:23: note: expanded from macro '__gthrw'
#define __gthrw(name) __gthrw2(__gthrw_ ## name,name,name)
                      ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/gthr-default.h:72:46: note: expanded from macro '__gthrw2'
  extern __typeof(type) name __attribute__ ((__weakref__(#name2))); \
                                             ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/gthr-default.h:115:1: error: weakref declaration must have
      internal linkage
__gthrw(pthread_mutexattr_init)
^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/gthr-default.h:81:23: note: expanded from macro '__gthrw'
#define __gthrw(name) __gthrw2(__gthrw_ ## name,name,name)
                      ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/gthr-default.h:72:46: note: expanded from macro '__gthrw2'
  extern __typeof(type) name __attribute__ ((__weakref__(#name2))); \
                                             ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/gthr-default.h:116:1: error: weakref declaration must have
      internal linkage
__gthrw(pthread_mutexattr_settype)
^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/gthr-default.h:81:23: note: expanded from macro '__gthrw'
#define __gthrw(name) __gthrw2(__gthrw_ ## name,name,name)
                      ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/gthr-default.h:72:46: note: expanded from macro '__gthrw2'
  extern __typeof(type) name __attribute__ ((__weakref__(#name2))); \
                                             ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/gthr-default.h:117:1: error: weakref declaration must have
      internal linkage
__gthrw(pthread_mutexattr_destroy)
^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/gthr-default.h:81:23: note: expanded from macro '__gthrw'
#define __gthrw(name) __gthrw2(__gthrw_ ## name,name,name)
                      ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/gthr-default.h:72:46: note: expanded from macro '__gthrw2'
  extern __typeof(type) name __attribute__ ((__weakref__(#name2))); \
                                             ^
16 errors generated.
```

Is there something else I need to do to make clang work on my system?  Or is my built-from-source install totally screwed up?

Comment: (1) Try `clang++`. (2) Your installation seems to use the headers that came with your RHEL-provided `gcc-4.1.2`. That may well be too old to work with clang 3.2.

Comment: Same problems.  Yeah, that's what I was afraid of.